# Laravel - is Route::controller safe?

Tags: php, security, laravel, laravel-routing

I keep wondering whether allowing Laravel to resolve the controller methods in a RESTful way is safe.

I always use `Route::controller` to bind routes to my controllers, but is it safe from a web security standpoint? What could be the possible caveats of this approach? What would be the benefits of explicitly tying routes to controller methods, like so:

`Route::get('user', 'UserController@getUser')`

instead of

`Route::controller('user', 'UserController');`

Comment: Delve into Laravel's source code and you will have first hand good insight :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I keep wondering whether allowing Laravel to resolve the controller
>   methods in a RESTful way is safe

What could be the risk that you are worried about? It's safe, there is no security risk.

> What would be the benefits of explicitly tying routes to controller
>   methods

Easy to maintain and better readability and more flexible (i.e. `URL` could be anything, you can chose).

I prefer `explicit` route declaration and it's always better if you don't have valid reasons for using `RESTful` routes.

Comment: I've read somewhere that it is "less safe", but the author never gave an explanation. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: I don't think there is any risk, but explicit routing is better and you are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to worry about safety, it's safe.
When you use RESTful Routes its easier to maintain, and your routes file doesn't get full of Route::get, Route::post.

When using Route::controller, Laravel will analyse your method names. This way you can achieve this like this:

```
// app/routes.php
Route::controller('/user', 'UsersController');

// app/controllers/UsersController.php
class UsersController extends BaseController 
{
    public function getIndex() 
    {
        return 'GET request to /user';
    }

    public function postIndex()
    {
        return 'POST to /user';
    }

}
```

As you can see laravel automatically detects which HTTP-method to use (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE).
This way you don't have to specify all routes in  the routes.php but instead just use Route::controller.

And again, Route::controller is just as safe as Route::get.

Hope this helps you ;)